# Rotate the output of Plot3D

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, geometric-transform, rotation

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x^2 + y^2] Exp[-x^2] + Cos[x^2 + y^2]

g2 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[g2, RotationMatrix[-2 Pi/3, {0, 0, 1}]]]
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this: `GeometricTransformation[g2[[1]], 
  RotationMatrix[-2 Pi/3, {0, 1, 1}]] // Graphics3D`. `GeometricTransformation` works on the geometric object, not on the `Graphics3D` expression.

Comment: It is so simple...I guess it should be marked as "on hold" soon:-)! Seriously, there is something relevant in the documentation?

Comment: I agree that it can be puzzling (not a big fan of the implementation of geometric transformations), but the examples in the help show how it works - the `Graphics` or `Graphics3D` calls come after the transformation. So closing as "can be found in the documenation" might be justified - glad to help anyway!

Comment: And me, I am even more glad to receive so quickly your help:-)! Thank you very much.

Comment: Apprantly `Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[g2[[1]], RotationMatrix[-2 Pi/3, {0, 0, 1}]]]` will work too. Its not about the Graphics3D expression but about the Plot3D as this is a List of an GraphicsObject and an inner List of Formatting options. Try `Table[g[[i]], {i, 1, 2}]`. You want to extract the GraphicsObject from Plot3D for the transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand the solution proposed in the comments by `@YvesKlett` has bee sufficient. However, I gave it a go out of curiousity and this seemed to work fine:

**Code:**

```
(*Dummy function*)
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x^2 + y^2] Exp[-x^2] + Cos[x^2 + y^2]

(*Sample data*)
g2 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]

(*Operation*)
Rotate[g2, 180 Degree]
```

**Output:**

[image: Rotated plot]

**Reference:**
[Rotate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate.html)

Comment: This works because it is performing a 2D rotation of the rendered `Graphics3D` expression, which is treated like a 2D object (and rotated 180° in the screen plane) . For the 3D rotation specified in the question,  this will not work.